# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (BUG)

Tags: ios, broadcast, rtmp, red5, videocore

```
    ClientState: 1
ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
ClientState: 4
ClientState: 5
ClientState: 6
received server window size: 2500000
received peer bandwidth limit: 2500000 type: 2
Received invoke
pktId: 1
received invoke _result
tracked command: connect
ClientState: 7
received unknown packet type: 0x00
Received invoke
pktId: 2
received invoke _result
tracked command: releaseStream
Received invoke
pktId: 3
received invoke _result
tracked command: FCPublish
Received invoke
pktId: 4
received invoke _result
tracked command: createStream
ClientState: 8
Received invoke
pktId: 0
```

received invoke onStatus
And then the app crashes and stops inside `RTMPSession::parseStatusCode` - most of the times strncpy inside the do-while loop leads to an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception, sometimes a few lines later.
and

```
int ret = ((val[2]&0xff)) | ((val[1]&0xff) << 8) | ((val[0]&0xff)<<16) ; -------- bad excess code
```

Do you have any ideas on how this can be solved?

Additional information: we are using Red5 on server side.

Comment: Bad access means you are trying to access an object which has already been released (in your case the "val" array is most likely released). You can try to debug your code with NSZombies enabled to check when your object gets released.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans Yes,  there is no difference . its shown same as above. After I add NSZombies into project.                 Error:      strncpy(propVal, (char*)p, valLen);

Comment: if you debug your code, and place a breakpoint at this line, if you print val, what is the value?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans Yes, the value is :0 and ret = 32641  and getting an error at this point . static inline int get_be24(uint8_t* val) {
    int ret = ((val[2]&0xff)) | ((val[1]&0xff) << 8) | ((val[0]&0xff)<<16) ; --- error
    return ret;
}